# Best way for setting Up data for Unit testing

Tags: java, json, excel, unit-testing, testing

What is the best way of setting up data for `unit testing` spanning all possible test-cases ? I have different situations where I need to check for null exceptions and other custom `exceptions` . In order to test such exceptions I have to `setup` data again & again with some fields changed & some unchanged.Finally, my test method writes to an `excel` file & I have to assert against each column value (have `50` such columns) with the expected values. Should storing set up data and assertion expected data in `json` be a good approach here ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use TestNG [dataprovider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) for example:

```
//This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data Provider
//is named "test1"
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
   { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
 };
}

//This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
//named "test1"
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
 System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}
```

Also I recommend see this [list](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links#1-testing), may be you'll find better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit parameterized tests.

See: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Comment: I'm using Mockito and Junit for testing. I have never used parametrized tests. I'm not understanding how it will be helpful to my case?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, really: apply the same principles and practices to your test code that one would apply for well designed production code.

More specifically, extract common code that creates objects holding test data into reusable helper classes and/or methods, then use them from your test methods.

Using data files in XML, JSON, etc. is not a good idea when compared to using the Java language, which gives you a lot more power and flexibility when writing the tests.

As for test parameterization APIs as provided by JUnit and TestNG, I have yet to see a compelling use case for them.